# ReactJS: Initializing instance variable in component's getInitialState?

Tags: reactjs

Is initializing component's instance variable in getInitialState relevant?

For example:

```
var Chat = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {

    this.messages = []; // Instance variable initialization - EDIT: better as state variable?

    this.scrollToBottom = false; // EDIT - Instance variable which is not a state 

    return { 

       messages: [],

    };

  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {

    if(this.scrollToBottom){

     // Animate DOM

     this.scrollToBottom = false;

    }

  },

  // ...

});
```

I would like to do that to make react component's code cleaner.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Why would you want to keep a variable like that? you return messages: [] which will be put into the state and referenced trough this.state.messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that, but I would ask why you want to do that? What data would you store on the component that you don't want to store as state?

The point of putting it in the state is that React knows when you modify that state, and re-renders accordingly. If you define arbitrary properties on the instance React won't know about them.

Another good point about putting it in the state is that it makes it very easy to see where state is used and modified. Most bugs that occur in a component is related to state, so making the use of it obvious is really helpful.

Comment: Thank your answer. I was doing that to prevent too many trigger of -render: . However thanks to your answer I may reconsider to chose carefully my state and instance variable. I was thinking about doing that to store other instance variable like scrollToBottom to trigger a scroll to bottom in componentDidUpdate: Is it better to initialize instance variable in componentWillMount?

Comment: Is `scrollToBottom` a function? If that's the case, then it should absolutely be a method on the instance. If it's a boolean for whether the component should scroll to bottom, it sounds like it should be a prop and you'd use `getDefaultProps` to set the initial value.

Comment: scrollToBottom is a bool. Why should it be a prop instead of a instance variable? I am also using Firebase as database. Is it relevant to initialize this.firebaseRef as null in getInitialState: ?

Comment: By making it a prop, it's possible to override it by passing in a value for the prop which makes your component more flexible. If you don't need to be able to override it, I don't see a reason for making a variable of it since it never changes.

Comment: All things considered, if you *did* absolutely want to set a variable directly on `this`, I would do it in `componentWillMount`. Side effects in a getter method like `getInitialState` is confusing and error-prone, as the name and purpose of the function makes it seem like it should be a pure function.

Comment: Just to be clear, using instance variables is not considered an anti-pattern.  The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) state: "While `this.props` is set up by React itself and `this.state` has a special meaning, you are free to add additional fields to the class manually if you need to store something that is not used for the visual output.  *If you don't use something in `render()`, it shouldn't be in the state.*" (emphasis added).  I think the OP's concern about avoiding unnecessary renders is legit.